# Equivalences between $KC$, $T_2$, $US$ and the property $(\diamond)$

Tags: general-topology

**Definition.** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space. We say that $X$

1. is **$T_2$**, if for all $x, y\in X$ with $x\neq y$ there exist $U, V\in \tau$ disjoint such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$.
2. is **$T_1$**, if for all $x, z \in X$ with $x\neq z$ exist $U, V \in \tau$ such that $x\in U-V$ and $z\in V-U$.
3. is **KC**, if every compact subset in $X$ is closed in $X$.
4. is **$US$**, if every convergent sequence in $X$, has a unique limit.
5. has the property **$(\diamond)$** if for any two compact subsets $C$ and $D$ with $C\cap D=\emptyset$, there exists $U\in \tau$ such that $C\subset U$ and $D\cap U=\emptyset$ or $D\subset U$ and $C\cap U=\emptyset$.
6. is **locally compact** if for each $x\in X$ and $U\in \tau$ with $x\in U$ there is $V \in \tau$ such that $\overline{V}$ is compact and also $x\in V\subset \overline{V}\subset U$.
7. is **first countable** if every $x\in X$ has a countable local base.

I am studying the equivalences between the spaces $KC$, $T_2$, $US$ and the property $(\diamond)$. I have obtained the following results:

**Theorem 1.** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a first countable space. Then the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $X$ is $US$.
2. $X$ is $T_2$.
3. $X$ is $KC$.
4. $X$ is $T_1$ and satisfies the property $(\diamond)$

**Theorem 2.** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a locally compact space. Then the following conditios are equivalent.

1. $X$ is $T_2$.
2. $X$ is $KC$.

One of my questions is... Can Theorem 1 be written as follows?

**Theorem 3.** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a first countable space. Then the following conditions are equivalent.

1. $X$ is $US$.
2. $X$ is $T_2$.
3. $X$ is $KC$.
4. $X$ satisfies the property $(\diamond)$

I believe that it is not possible to say that these conditions are equivalent, for this, it is enough to show a space that is $US$ and that does not satisfy the property $(\diamond)$? or Do I have to show a first countable space that satisfies the property (*) but is not a $US$ space?

Second question... Can Theorem 2 be written as follows?

**Theorem 4.** Let $(X, \tau)$ be a locally compact space. Then the following conditios are equivalent.

1. $X$ is $T_2$.
2. $X$ is $KC$.
3. $X$ satisfies the property $(\diamond)$

I think it is possible to show that the theorem is true, but I can't conclude it yet. This is my attempt.

Proof: $T_2 \Rightarrow KC \Rightarrow (\diamond)$. I need to prove that $(\diamond) \Rightarrow T_2$.

Let $x, y\in X$ be with $x\neq y$, and $M, N\in \tau$ such that $x\in M$ and $y\in N$. Since $X$ is locally compact there are $W, V\in \tau$ such that $\overline{W}$ and $\overline{V}$ are compact and $x\in W\subset \overline{W} \subset M$, and $y\in V\subset \overline{V}\subset N$.

If $\overline{W} \cap \overline{V}=\emptyset$. Since $X$ satisfies property $(\diamond)$ then there is $U\in \tau$ such that $\overline{W}\subset U$ and $\overline{V}\cap U=\emptyset$, or $\overline{V}\subset U$ and $\overline{W}\cap U=\emptyset$.

Suppose $\overline{W}\subset U$ and $\overline{V}\cap U=\emptyset$. Then $x\in U$, $y\in V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$, therefore $X$ is $T_2$. If $\overline{V}\subset U$ and $\overline{W}\cap U=\emptyset$, analogously we conclude that $X$ is $T_2$.

If $\overline{W}\cap \overline{V}\neq \emptyset$. Then $M\cap N\neq \emptyset$ and we have the cases:

Case a) If $W\cap V=\emptyset$. Then we have $X$ is $T_2$.

Case b) If $W\cap V\neq \emptyset$. From here I cannot conclude.

I would appreciate it if you would support me with a counterexample for Theorem 3, a suggestion for the proof of Theorem 4 or a counterexample for this same theorem.